# Scope of function variables

Tags: powershell

I need to calculate number of `mp3` and `flac` files recursively. Here is my code:

```
function GetStat() 
{
    $mp3_count = 0 
    $flac_count = 0
    Set-Variable -Name mp3_count,flac_count -Option AllScope

    function getFiles($path) 
    {     
        foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
        {
            if (Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container) 
            {

                GetFiles $item.FullName
            } 
            else 
            { 
                if ($item.Extension -eq ".mp3")
                {                    
                    $mp3_count = $mp3_count + 1                 
                }

                if ($item.Extension -eq ".flac")
                {
                    $flac_count = $flac_count + 1                   
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    getFiles "Y:\music (flac)\Alternative"
    $mp3_count
    $flac_count
}
```

My function write `0, 0`, and it looks like `$mp3_count` and `flac_count` variables reset every time function `getFiles()` is called.

How can I fix the code ?

Comment: You could replace all occurrences of `$mp3_count` with `$global:mp3_count` so that you always read from and write to the same variable at the global scope.

Comment: You create variables as global, but set them later as undefined (local in function). Use a scope modifier as stated above. Also, you can replace all this with `$files = dir -path "Y:\music (flac)\Alternative" -file -recurse; $mp3_count = @($files | where { $_.extension -match 'mp3$' }).Count; $flac_count = @($files | where { $_.extension -match 'flac$' }).Count`

Comment: Or `$flac_count,$mp3_count = dir "Y:\music (flac)\Alternative" -file -recurse | where { $_.extension -match '\.flac$|\.mp3$' } | group extension | sort name | select -expand count`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could skip all of this by simply using `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`. But if you want to implement recursion yourself, here's a couple of pointers.

I would recommend against writing to variables outside the local scope!

Make your recursive function return a hashtable instead, then add the values for each recursion to the local hashtable:

```
function Get-FileCount 
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Container})]
        [string]$Path = (Resolve-Path $PWD),

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string[]]$Extensions = @('flac','mp3')
    )

    # build local table to hold counts per extension
    $ExtensionCount = @{}

    # add dot to extensions if missing
    $Extensions = $Extensions |ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace '^(?=[^\.])','.'
    }

    # retrieve all items at current $Path
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path |ForEach-Object {
        # recurse if directory
        if($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]){
            # retrieve count from subfolder
            $Subcount = Get-FileCount -Path $_.FullName -Extensions $Extensions
            foreach($Extension in $Subcount.Keys){
                # add results from recursive call for each identified extension to current count
                $ExtensionCount[$Extension] += $Subcount[$Extension]
            }
        } 
        elseif($_.Extension -in $Extensions) {
            # increment count for the found extension in local $Path
            $ExtensionCount[$_.Extension]++
        }
    }

    # return the counting table
    return $ExtensionCount
}
```

Now you can retrieve the counts of each type with:

```
Get-FileCount "Y:\music (flac)\Alternative"
```

And you don't need to rewrite anything if you want to add new file types:

```
Get-FileCount "Y:\music (flac)\Alternative" -Extensions flac,mp3,avi,ogg
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking don't touch the global scope unless you absolutely need to. There's a whole bunch of extra stuff in your function including an unnecessary nested function. This is a more practical way of doing the same thing:

```
# Functions should be named Verb-<Whatever>
function Get-MediaStats ($Path) 
{
    # Everything that was here was extra and unneeded.
    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse)
    {
        if ($item.Extension -eq ".mp3")
        {                    
            $mp3_count++                 
        }

        if ($item.Extension -eq ".flac")
        {
            $flac_count++               
        }
    } 

    # This creates an object... The 'return' or 'write-output' is implied.
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'MP3Count' = $mp3_count
        'FLACCount' = $flac_count
    }

}

# Instead of nested functions you can call the function like so... 
# Because it's returning a an object the variable $Result will contain the output.
$Results = Get-MediaStats C:\Path\To\Files
$Results
```

Note also that you can increment variables with `$Var++` instead of `$Var = $Var + 1`

To pass stuff between functions or outside of functions using objects and not global variables is the correct way to do it:

```
Function Return-Something {
    Write-Output 'Something'
}

Function Return-Something {
    return 'Something'
}

Function Return-Something {
    'Something'
}

Function Return-Something {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Something' = 'Something'
    }
}
```

Any one of those would work if you did `$Result = Return-Something`

Answer (score 0):

I would get all files recursively with `$items=Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter "*.mp3" -Path $pathToQuery`. Then user `$items.Count`. You can optimize for one scan with multiple extensions and then before the count filter with `Where-Object` with your custom reasoning. For example

```
$items=Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter @("*.mp3","*.flac") -Path $pathToQuery
($items|Where-Object {#filter1 reasoning}).Count
($items|Where-Object {#filter2 reasoning}).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathias R. Jessen already provided an excellent answer, but for something simple you could use `Get-ChildItem` with the `-Recurse` parameter, and pipe that to `Group-Object` to make this so much simpler.

```
Function Get-FileCount{
Param(
    [string]$Path,
    [string[]]$Extensions = ".MP3",".FLAC"
)
    # Sanitize extensions
    $Extensions = $Extensions -replace "^(?:.*\.)?([^\.]+)$",'.$1'
    #Locate, filter, and group files
    Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where{ $_.Extension -in $extensions } | Group Extension | Select Name,Count
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
Get-FileCount "Y:\music (flac)\Alternative"
```

And it would output something like:

```
Name    Count
----    -----
.mp3    37
.flac   163
```